# How to increase height of view using panresponder in react native?

Tags: react-native, animation

I am trying to create two sibling views changing there height. When we drag a view then its height should increase and other height should decrease & vice varsa. I am using pan responder to do this but any other approach will also be great. Issue is when i drag then handle the view moves up or down but its height does not changes. Similarly other view also not changing its height.

```js
const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

const panResponder = useRef(
  PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: () => {
      pan.setOffset({
        x: pan.x._value,
        y: pan.y._value
      });
    },
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
      [
        null,
        { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
      ], { useNativeDriver: false }
    ),
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      pan.flattenOffset();
    }
  })
).current;

return <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ top: 'never', bottom: 'never' }}>
<Animated.View style={[{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', flex: 1 }]}>

</Animated.View>
    <Animated.View style={[{
      height: 100,
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
    }, {
      transform: [{ translateY: pan.y }]
    }]}>
      <Animated.View style={[{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingVertical: 5, backgroundColor: '#f0f3f7' }]}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <Block flex={false} color='#ccc' radius={10} style={{ height: 5, width: 35 }} />
      </Animated.View>
    </Animated.View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```